# creating a column based on text using Text.Contains power bi

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am adding a custom column that reads from a text column.
I want to add 1 where [Site Survey Comments] contains TDY and 0 if not.
but sometimes [Site Survey Comments] is null and I need to replace it by 0.

I tried to do it without specifying null output then check for error then replace it with 0. but I thought there mightbe a better way to enhance my actuall function for future data

**here my code:**

```
if Text.Contains([Site Survey Comments],"TDY") then 1 
else if not Text.Contains([Site Survey Comments],"TDY") then 0 
else [Site Survey Comments]= null then 0
```

Comment: `if [T] <> null and Text.Contains([T], "v") then 1 else 0`